# XSLT Pandas - How to Pull the Grandchild value to a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xslt, parent-child

I'm trying to flatten an XML structure into a Pandas (Python) Dataframe using a custom XSLT with the read_xml function.

Given the following XML Structure:

```
<ml:Meals xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
  <ml:Meal>
    <ml:type>lunch</ml:type>
    <ml:main_course>turkey sandwich</ml:main_course>
    <ml:dessert>
      <ml:name>Cookie</ml:name>
    </ml:dessert>
  </ml:Meal>
</ml:Meals>
```

I ultimately want my dataframe to look like this:

```
+-----+---------------+-------+
| type|    main_course|dessert|
+-----+---------------+-------+
|lunch|turkey sandwich| Cookie|
+-----+---------------+-------+
```

Struggling a bit with my XSLT syntax. I feel like I'm close with this but not quite there. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[@ml:dessert]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ml:name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the expected result as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that instead of:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[@ml:dessert]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ml:name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

you want:

```
  <xsl:template match="ml:dessert">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="ml:name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reach this result with pandas `read_xml()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xmlstr = """<ml:Meals xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
  <ml:Meal>
    <ml:type>lunch</ml:type>
    <ml:main_course>turkey sandwich</ml:main_course>
    <ml:dessert>
      <ml:name>Cookie</ml:name>
    </ml:dessert>
  </ml:Meal>
</ml:Meals>"""

f = StringIO(xmlstr)

df = pd.read_xml(f, xpath = './/ml:Meal/*', namespaces={'ml':'http://www.food.com'})
df1 = df.ffill().dropna()
print(df1.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
 type     main_course   name
lunch turkey sandwich Cookie
```

*Option* with xml.etree.ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

xmlstr = """<ml:Meals xmlns:ml="http://www.food.com">
  <ml:Meal>
    <ml:type>lunch</ml:type>
    <ml:main_course>turkey sandwich</ml:main_course>
    <ml:dessert>
      <ml:name>Cookie</ml:name>
    </ml:dessert>
  </ml:Meal>
</ml:Meals>"""

f = StringIO(xmlstr)

root = ET.parse(f).getroot()
ET.register_namespace('ml','http://www.food.com')

name = root.find('.//{*}name')
dessert = root.find('.//{*}dessert')

meal = root.find('.//{*}Meal')
meal.remove(dessert)
meal.append(name)

#ET.dump(root)

df = pd.read_xml(ET.tostring(root))
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```